# Showing date in Paraview's Annotate Time Filter

Tags: python, visualization, paraview

I have a time dependent data set where each frame corresponds to a certain date. I need to show the time annotation, much like what Annotate Time Filter does, but show the date instead of time as a float value. How can I do that?

In python I can convert the time index to a date with `datetime` for instance:

```
init_date = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
time_step = 3600.
itime = 20
date = init_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=itime*time_step)
print(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

Comment: You can record a script and then check the code.

Comment: I can use Tools->Start Trace to get Python code for creating an annotation filter. However, it will just show a call to `AnnotateTimeFilter(Input=...)`. I'd need to modify the filter itself or create a Programmable filter that modifies its output.

Comment: I just checked the [last ParaView Guide](https://www.paraview.org/paraview-guide/) and it has several material on using ParaView through Python.

Comment: You are still not answering the question...